# add image to in first two of three javascript results

Tags: javascript, twitter, blogger

I have a blogger script that pulls the latest three twitter posts from an account and am I tweaked it to add in an image divider at the bottom of the post but do NOT want to see the divider at the bottom of the last post. I am stuck with the syntax to use to count the first two then exclude the image (or rewrite the line without the image) in the third.

Here is the code block:

```
function twitterCallback2(twitters) 
{
    var statusHTML = [];
    for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++)
    {
        var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
        var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) 
        {
            return '<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank">'+url+'</a>';
        }).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) 
        {
            return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
        });

        statusHTML.push('<li><span>'+status+'</span> <a class="date" href="http://twitter.com/'+username+'/statuses/'+twitters[i].id_str+'" target="_blank"><br /><p style="text-align:left; margin-top:4px;"><img src="../images/news/twitter-bird.png" style="margin:3px 2px 0 0;">'+relative_time(twitters[i].created_at)+'</a></p><img src="../images/news/twitter-divider.png" style="margin-top:4px;"></li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('twitter_update_list').innerHTML = statusHTML.join('');
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but this should work:

```
function twitterCallback2(twitters) {
  var statusHTML = [];
  for (var i=0; i<twitters.length; i++){
    var username = twitters[i].user.screen_name;
    var status = twitters[i].text.replace(/((https?|s?ftp|ssh)\:\/\/[^"\s\<\>]*[^.,;'">\:\s\<\>\)\]\!])/g, function(url) {
      return '<a href="'+url+'" target="_blank">'+url+'</a>';
    }).replace(/\B@([_a-z0-9]+)/ig, function(reply) {
      return  reply.charAt(0)+'<a href="http://twitter.com/'+reply.substring(1)+'">'+reply.substring(1)+'</a>';
    });
    var htmlToPush = '<li><span>'+status+'</span> <a class="date" href="http://twitter.com/'+username+'/statuses/'+twitters[i].id_str+'" target="_blank"><br /><p style="text-align:left; margin-top:4px;"><img src="../images/news/twitter-bird.png" style="margin:3px 2px 0 0;">'+relative_time(twitters[i].created_at)+'</a></p>';
    if (i<twitters.length-1)
        htmlToPush += '<img src="../images/news/twitter-divider.png" style="margin-top:4px;">';
    htmlToPush += '</li>';
    statusHTML.push(htmlToPush);
  }
  document.getElementById('twitter_update_list').innerHTML = statusHTML.join('');
}
```

Comment: Maybe untested by you but Works perfectly!! Thanks for your help!